# Deck of cards ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i seem to be having a problem with my deck class iterating through the Suits array.

Card class:

```
//David Diienno
//Lab 01
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Card {

private String m_rank; // card rank: a number between 2 and 10, or        Jack, Queen, King or Ace

private char m_suit; // card suit: S, C, H, or D (spades, clubs, hearts, or diamonds)
// Helpful supporting structures

private static String [] Ranks = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

private static char [] Suits = {'C','H','D','S'};
// Default constructor: sets card rank to 2 and card suit to H

public Card(){
    //setting default card to a 2 of hearts
    m_rank = Ranks[0];

    m_suit = Suits[1];

}
// Accessors and Mutators
public Card(String Rank, char suit){
    if(isValidRank(Rank) == true){
        m_rank = Rank;

    }
    if(isValidSuit(suit) == true){
        m_suit = suit;
    }

} 

public String getRank() {
    System.out.println(m_rank);
    return m_rank;
}

public char getSuit() {
    System.out.println(this.suitToString());
    return m_suit;
}

public void setRank(String rank) {
    // Make sure to validate provided input
    if (isValidRank(rank) == true){
        m_rank = rank;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The rank you entered is invalid");
    }

}

public void setSuit(char suit) {
    // Make sure to validate provided input
    if(isValidSuit(suit) == true){
        m_suit = suit;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("The suit you entered is invalid");
    }

}
// Method toString – returns string representation of the card that looks as follows:
// 2 of Hearts, 3 of Spades, Jack of Diamonds, etc.
// Requirement: you must use switch statement to convert character to string.
//
// Hint: card’s rank is already a string. Therefore you only need to convert card suit into
// a string that reads “Clubs”, “Spades”, “Hearts” or “Diamond  s”
public String suitToString(){
    switch(m_suit){

        case 'c': return "Clubs";

        case 'h': return "Hearts";

        case 'd': return "Diamonds";

        case 's': return "Spades";
        default: return "Hearts";

    }
}

public String toString() {

    String data = "You have a " + m_rank + " of " + this.suitToString();
    return data;

}
// Supporting static methods
// Returns an array of possible card ranks

public static String [ ] getPossibleRanks() {

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Ranks));
    for(int i = 0; i < Card.Ranks.length; i ++){
        System.out.println(Ranks[i]);

    }
    return Ranks;
}

// Returns an array of possible card suits
public static char [ ] getPossibleSuits() {
    for(int i = 0; i < Card.Suits.length;i++){

        System.out.println(Suits[i]);

    }
    return Suits;
}

public boolean isValidRank (String r){
    for(int i = 0; i < Card.Ranks.length; i++ ){
        if(Card.Ranks[i].equals( r)){
            return true;

        }

    }
    return false;

}

public boolean isValidSuit (char s){
    for (int i = 0; i < Card.Suits.length; i++){

        if(Card.Suits[i] == s){

            return true ;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
}
```

Deck class :

```
import java.util.*;
public class DeckOfCards extends Card {
private ArrayList <Card> deck;
private Card card;
private  String [] Ranks = super.getPossibleRanks();
private  char [] Suits = super.getPossibleSuits();

// public void resetDeckOfCards() {

public DeckOfCards()
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for(int s = 0; s < Suits.length; s++)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < Ranks.length; r++){
            card = new Card(Ranks[r],Suits[s]);
            deck.add(card);
        }

    }

}
public void display(){
    System.out.println(deck);

}
//public Card getCard() { /* ... */ }
//Remove a random card from the Array List of cards and return its value from this method Notes:
//￼1. Ensure that there is at least one card in the ArrayList of Cards
//2. If there are no more cards left in the ArrayList of Cards, reset the Deck of Cards
//3. Use class Random to create a random number which will be an index into ArrayList of Cards
//4. Remove and return card stored in the ArrayList of Cards in the randomly created index
// Return an ArrayList of specified size (i.e. returned cards are being removed from the deck). //
// Notes:
// 1. Use method getCard() to retrieve a single card
// 2. Validate the value of size passed into this method and return     null if size is invalid
//public ArrayList<Card> getHand(int size) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Why when i display my array list it doesn't iterate through the suits but it does through the ranks, i still get 52 cards but all with same suit.

Comment: Just as a side code review, there is no need for `== true`. Just do `if(isValidRank(Rank))`

Comment: If this is your lab work, the whole point is that you learn to debug. Break down the code into smaller segments, test each of them individually... that's the point of your classes; the aim is not to get someone else to do it.

Comment: @Ascalonian  thanks for your responses, i was just stuck on one thing, and thats all i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem appears to be that your `Suits` array has capital letters, but your `suitToString` method is using a switch statement where lower case letters are used. Since the default case is Hearts, I bet all your cards are hearts.